# Create an instance based on a stringvalue

Tags: c#, reflection

I wish to create an instance of a class, using a string value.
According to what I read here: [Activator.CreateInstance Method (String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4(v=vs.110).aspx) it should work!

```
public class Foo
{
    public string prop01 { get; set; }
    public int prop02 { get; set; }
}   

//var assName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
var assName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().FullName; 
var foo = Activator.CreateInstance(assName, "Foo");
```

Why won't this work? 
I get the following error:

> {"Could not load type 'Foo' from assembly 'theassemblyname,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.":"Foo"}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of the simple type name, you should use the full qualified type name, including the entire namespace.

Like this:

```
var foo = Activator.CreateInstance(assName, "Bar.Baz.Foo");
```

As [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> The fully qualified name of the preferred type.

Answer (score 3):

Either use fully qualified name, as proposed already:

```
var foo = Activator.CreateInstance(assName, "FooNamespace.Foo");
```

Or get the type by the name:

```
var type = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                                      .First(x=>x.Name=="Foo");
var foo = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

More simple is to use directly your Foo class:

```
var foo = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Foo));
```

Comment: you could accept solution of @Patrick Hofman and give one upvote for mine :)

Comment: Note that the second sample is dangerous if you have multiple types with the same name but within another namespace.

Comment: The third sample could be simplified as `new Foo()` since you already know the type.